# nested filter array method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The purpose of this code is to filter items by color. The filtered is value is not updating to the items that match the color. The filterData function is suppose to filter through the products and then filter through the colors in the array and return the products that are of that color

```
state = {
    filtered:this.props.products,
    color:[],
    size:'all',
    price:'all',
    type:'all'
}

change = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]:[...this.state.color,value]
    }, () => {
        this.filterData();
    })
}

filterData = () => {
    if (this.state.color) {
        var newData = this.props.products.filter(product => {
            return this.state.color.filter(c => {
                return c === product.colors 
            })
        })
    }
    this.setState({
        filtered:newData
    })
}

render() {
    let list = this.state.filtered.map(product => {
        return(
            <div className="product" key={product.product_id}>
                <Link to = {{ pathname: '/'+product.product_id}}>
                    <img className="product_image"src={product.image[0]} />
                </Link>
                <div className="product_info">
                    <p className="product_title">{product.title}</p>
                    <p className="product_price">${product.price}.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

Comment: Looks like products.colors is a array, you cannot compare arrays that way, you should check whether the selected color is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your filter function, like this:

```
filterData = () => {
  var newData = this.propts.products;

  if(this.state.color) {
      newData = this.props.products.filter(product => {
        return product.colors.some(color => {
          return this.state.color.includes(color);
        });
      })
  }

  this.setState({
      filtered:newData
  })
}
```

Besides fixing the issue of comparing arrays directly, this functions returns true only when at least on of the color of a product is in the list of colors selected by the user.

Of course that you have to account the fact that `newData` is only defined when `this.state.color` is set so you should do something about it (I fixed it by assigning a default value).

**Update:** BTW, your code is awful, you should take some time to format your code accordingly so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be simplified a fair bit. It's hard to tell for sure without seeing what the actually data structure of an item in the color array and what a product looks like. This new filterData method should fix it. This is what I am imagining the data looks like:

```
this.state.color = ["red","blue","green","purple", ...];

this.state.products = [
    {name: "product1", price: 10, color: "orange"},
    {name: "product2", price: 20, color: "red"},
    ...
]
```

You can also utilize some ES6 features to make your code cleaner and more readable. A big issue is you defined newData within your "if(this.state.color)" block so will always be undefined when it hits "this.setState".

First you should filter the products, and the condition in the filter being if the products color is within the color array. You can achieve this by using "indexOf" and checking if the index is greater than -1. -1 means it does not exist in the array, anything greater is the color's index position, meaning it exists.

```
filterData = () => {
    if(this.state.color){
        let { color } = this.state;
        let { products } = this.props;
        let newData = products.filter(product => {
            if(color.indexOf(product.colors) > -1)
                return product;
        }
        this.setState({filtered: newData})
    }
}
```

Based on the example data I provided above, only product2 would be returned since it's color ("red") is included in the color array.
Hope this helps!